# Trying to parse xhr.responseText

Tags: jquery, ajax, regex, xmlhttprequest

I'm using jquery get to call an ASP MVC controller. Which returns a partial view. i.e. a bunch of html

In the case of an error I'd like to populate some info for the user but ASP MVC is sending a full page back so I need to grab text out of it.

I've tried:

```
$('#edit').ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings, exception) {
        var item = xhr.responseText.text();
        var response = item.match(/.*<body.*>(.*)<\/body>.*/);
        if (!response) {
            $(this).html('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' Message:' + xhr.statusText);
        }
        else {
            $(this).html(response);
        };
    });
```

But I get Uncaught TypeError: [followed by the contents of xhr.responseText] has no method text

If I call match directly on responseText I get null as a result.

I'm guessing I've got some fundamental misunderstanding going on so if anyone can help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also modify your regular expression to include newline characters, i.e.

```
var response = xhr.responseText.match(/.*<body.*>([\s\S]*)<\/body>.*/);
```

Comment: That helped me getting contents inside bode, where xhr.responseText was returning a complete page's html.

Answer (score 3):

`xhr.responseText` is a string ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest#responseText)), and there is no native method of the `String` prototype named `text()`. Thus the line below, where you try to call `.text()` off the `responseText`, causes that error:

```
var item = xhr.responseText.text();
```

Since `match()` is a method on the `String` prototype, you would just call it directly off the `responseText` if you're trying to find something therein.

```
var response = xhr.responseText.match(/.*<body.*>(.*)<\/body>.*/);
```

Whether it finds anything from there, we'll see ;)

Comment: Ah, I was calling text as it hadn't worked on the responseText itself to see if that would help...

Comment: I see, well, you can't just make up random method names and call them just cuz something doesn't work... :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status') ;

$('form').ajaxForm({

    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        $('#ttt').html(xhr.responseText.replace(/[\r\n]/g, ' ').match(/<!--t-->([\s\S]*)<!--t1-->/));
     }

}); 



})();
```

Comment: I asked this question on Aug 4 '11 - I don't even remember what I was working on at the time. You should try to avoid resurrecting old questions. Particularly ones that have an accepted answer - unless you really believe there's something you can improve on. In which case say why you think your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is going to run into trouble from the newlines in your HTML.

```
var response = xhr.responseText.replace(/[\r\n]/g, ' ').match(/<body.*>(.*)<\/body>/);
```

That cleans out the newlines first.